# Display image as with double data type in open cv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

This is one of the basic question.I wanted to display a `cv::Mat` structure whose data type is double. Is it possible to do so or should I convert to any other data type as in matlab? If so how can i do it? I am working on OpenCV with C++.

Comment: yes, you can imshow() float or double images. if they're in the [0..1] range, opencv mutiplicates them with 255, if not they get converted to bytes internally ( in that case it might need some upscaling for nice results )

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [convertTo()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#mat-convertto) function to get your image in the CV_8U format and then display.